# Troubles with motors for arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

**Why won't my motors work?**

My setup is as followed:

- arduino mega 2560 -> L296N motor controller -> Gikfun 3-6v dc motors.

To power the motors the setup is as followed:

- arduino mega 2560 5v -> L296N motor controller.
- 9v battery -> LM2596 buck converter(7-8v) -> L296N motor controller.

I have 2 issues.

- Issue 1: that no matter the code, the motors seem to only want to run at maximum speed. The code can be the simple example code or my code **see bottom**.
- Issue 2: When given a code that changes the speed, it only works for one motor and the other motor will not run regardless if the first motor is hooked up or not, it will not work with the example code provided nor will it work in my code **see bottom**.

Note that this is not a simple wiring fix. Either the code is wrong, my hardware setup is wrong, or my hardware may not be functioning properly. **Thank you for taking the time to review.**

```
// ex code:  
int a = 2;  
int b = 3;  
int c = 22;  
int d = 23;  
int e = 24;  
int f = 25; 

void setup(){  
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);

void loop() {  
  digitalWrite(c, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(d, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(e, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(f, LOW);  
  analogWrite(a, 0);  
  analogWrite(b, 0);
```

```
// ex code:  
for (int i = 0; i > 150; i++){  
  analogWrite(a, i);  
  analogWrite(b, i);  
  delay(1000);  
} 

for (int i = 150; i <= 0; --i){  
  analogWrite(a, i);    
  analogWrite(b, i);  
  delay(1000);  
}
```

```
/* my code. Note that the timed function is not finished.   
* I also x'd out 4 motors for easy debugging purposes.  
*/
// Motor 1
int a = 2;
int a1 = 22;
int a2 = 23;
// Motor 2
int b = 3;
int b1 = 24;
int b2 = 25;
// Motor 3
int c = 4;
int c1 = 26;
int c2 = 27;
// Motor 4
int d = 5;
int d1 = 28;
int d2 = 29;
// Motor 5
int e = 6;
int e1 = 30;
int e2 = 31;
// Motor 6
int f = 7;
int f1 = 32;
int f2 = 33;
// Motor halt
unsigned int i;
int x;
int x1;
int x2;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(x2, OUTPUT);
}
void motor1(){
  digitalWrite(a1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  analogWrite(a, 0);
  if (a = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorA not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(a, 0);
  if (a = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorAr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  delay(250);
}
void motor2(){
  digitalWrite(b1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
  analogWrite(b, 0);
  if (b = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorB not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(b, 0);
  if (b = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorBr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
  delay(250);

}
void motor3(){
  digitalWrite(x1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (c = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorC not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (c = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorCr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);

}
void motor4(){
  digitalWrite(x1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (d = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorD not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (d = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorDr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);

}
void motor5(){
  digitalWrite(x1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (e = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorE not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (e = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorEr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);

}
void motor6(){
  digitalWrite(x1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (f = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorF not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(x, 0);
  if (f = 1){
    Serial.println(" MotorFr not working");
  }
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(x1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(x2, LOW);
  delay(250);

}
void timed(){
  analogWrite(a, i);
  digitalWrite(a1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  analogWrite(b, i);
  digitalWrite(b1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
  analogWrite(b, i);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(a, i);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(a1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(a2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(b2, LOW);
}
void loop(){
  motor1();
  motor2();
  motor3();
  motor4();
  motor5();
  motor6();
  if (i = 0){
    i++;
  }
  if (i >=100){
    --i;
  }
  timed();

}
```

Comment: Want to narrow this down to one specific question?

Comment: @Ghetti - Please edit your question and add the actual sketch(s) you are using. A picture, or preferably a "wiring diagram" (schematic) of the entire set-up would also help us to help you :)

Comment: @VE7JRO The code doesn't matter. However I have added the code I've been using. The setup is as simple as what is explained. No breadboards in the way, not complicated. Everything is directly connected. So wiring is not an issue. Please go through and explain what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say much about the example code, that you mentioned. The posted example code is not complete, also the second part with the for loop is plain wrong. A for loop looks like this

```
for(<Variable initialization>; <Condition for running the loop>; <Action done for every loop iteration>)
```

So the condition in the middle is the condition for the loop running. If the condition evaluates to `false`, the loop will not run anymore. You have the line

```
for (int i = 0; i > 150; i++)
```

where `i` has the value zero at the start of the first iteration. zero is not bigger than 150, so the condition will evaluate to false. Thus the for loop will never run. The situation is similar with the second for loop of the example code. Where did you get that code? I think you should not trust this source very much, if it gives you this code.

---

Your own code also has some errors:

- You are doing the if statement for equality wrong. If you want to check for equality, you need to use double equal signs. A single equal sign means an assertion (so you are actually changing the variable instead of check it's value), which will always evaluate to true. An example of a correct if statement is this:

  ```
  if(i == 0)
  ```
- You are doing things like

  ```
  analogWrite(a, 0);
  ```

  all over your code. but nearly always you are doing a

  ```
  if(a == 1)
  ```

  directly after it. This does not make sense. The first parameter of `analogWrite()` is the pin number, where you want to output the PWM voltage. A pin number is constant, why should it ever change, unless you are plugging the motor into other pins. So the above if statement will not check, if the motor runs or not. It will compare the pin number to 1, which is always false, since none of the pin numbers, that you used, is 1.
- Again with the line

  ```
  analogWrite(a, 0);
  ```

  You are never providing a different second parameter as zero in your code (except for the `timed()` function, but I will get to this later). So the corresponding pin (here pin a aka 2) is turned off aka outputs LOW. With H-bridge controllers like the L296N, you use 2 digital pins to set the direction and then provide a PWM voltage (mostly at the enable pin) to change the speed. But as described, you never output a PWM voltage, so the motors cannot run, if you connected them corrected.
- Connected the the previous sentence. Your code will not run any motors. But since you wrote, that they actually do run, this means, that the hardware is also a problem. Please revisit tutorials on how to use the L296N with an Arduino or provide information about your wiring by editing your question.
- In your `loop()` function you have this passage:

  ```
  if (i == 0){
       i++;
  }
  if (i >=100){
      --i;
  }
  ```

  (I already corrected the double equal signs as described above). If `i`is exactly zero, `i` will be incremented. If `i` is greater or equal to 100, it will decrement. It only changes in this code portion and it will be initialized implicitly with a value of zero at the startup of the program. So the first if statement will trigger exactly once. Then `i` is not equal to zero, so it will not increment or even ever change again. Also `i` is not greater or equal to 100 (it is 1), so it will never decrement. Your code sets `i` to 1 once, and then never changes it again. That cannot be, what you tried to do. If you want a sweep from 0 to 100 and then from 100 to 0, you need an extra variable for the direction. Something like this:

  ```
  boolean direction=false; // define this at global scope
  ...
  // the following code would replace your `i` related code in your loop function
  if(direction){
      i++;
  } else {
      i--;
  }
  if(i==0) direction = true;
  if(i>=100) direction = false;
  ```
- Connected to the previous issue: Since `i` stays `1` forever, you also only write a PWM duty cycle of 1 out of 255 to the motors a and b inside the `timed()` function. A value this small is most likely not enough to even move the rotor of the motors (since motors also experience friction). Again, these motors should not run with your current code. If you change the `i` related code like I suggested above, the code should run the motors with changing speed. But also note, that this would still be a very slow change. A full run of the `timed()` function takes 4s (since the two 2s delays). With 100 steps, a full sweep from 0 to 100 will take 400s (aka 6.7 minutes) and the same time back to 0. (And this isn't accounting for the huge delays from the previous motor functions. With this you won't be able to see the change, until you wait really long time for it)
- You wrote, that you are using a 9V block battery as power source. If it is a 9V block battery, then you should know, that these batteries are not made for providing much current. They are made for low power applications. For driving motors for a longer time over battery or driving more motors at the same time, you should consider using a different battery (for example multiple AA batteries in series). As your motors currently run from it, you seem to get away with it, which is just fine. I just wanted to provide the information, in the case you reach this limit at some point.

---

All in all I can only agree with VE7JRO, that you should start with code for 1 single motor. Then, if it works like it should, you can move on and add the next motor. This will ensure, that you are getting things right early in the process and that you don't generate a big mountain of problems to cope with at once.